# How to install Ubuntu in my pc when i don't have enough space in C:\ drive?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I want to install ubuntu alongside Windows 10 (which is already installed in my pc) in my pc, i was trying to shrink volume of C:\ drive by disk management but my C:\ drive don't have enough space . Will it work if i shrink my D:\ or E:\ drive in stead of C:\?

I also tried using USB drive by downloading unetbootin but found no result.

Please give a detailed explanation if possible.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't care where on your disk it gets some space, just free up some unpartitioned space, don't make a partition or format it, the Ubuntu installer will do that itself.

Comment: @ByteCommander okay thanks, but when i download ubuntu14.04 in my pc do i have to burn burn disk image or mount it?

Comment: You must burn the iso either to a DVD or to an USB drive (using tools like e.g. Rufus) and then boot your computer from that medium. You might want to look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks a lot,but do i must have to shrink volume or only downloading and burning will work?

Comment: If you edit your question to include a screenshot of gparted or Windows Disk Management app, I can make a better recommendation. Boot to the Ubuntu DVD/USB if you need to for gparted.

Comment: that'll be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utility [gparted within a live USB or CD install to resize your disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T5Zm.png) offline. It should come preinstalled however if it is not you can run 'sudo apt-get install gparted' to install it.

I happen to find the ['Universal USB Installer'](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) the easiest to use on Windows whenever I try to make a bootable USB key.

Comment: Oh thats nice of them :) Ill update this answer.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, shrinking the D or E drive can work. Look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOfnvbdWhrs).

For USB bootable OS, do this :

1. Download ISO file of ubuntu (any version)
2. Download Universal USB Installer (UUI) from [here](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
3. Connect your USB drive and run UUI and follow the process.
4. After 10-20 minutes it will create a bootable USB.
5. Restart your system and boot from the USB drive.
6. Install it and enjoy Ubuntu on your system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  **;-)** As videos do not contain any text that is searchable, pure video answers are not allowed here...  Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the video into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link to the video at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: -1 Video instead of actual instructions; not all versions of Ubuntu are applicable here; better directions for creating a live USB already exist [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).